# Process for receiving xml from remote, insert into MYSQL in JSON format?

Tags: php, mysql, json, xml

I have a server that receives JSON structures from various sources and then inserts them into MYSQL via a listening type script. (as JSON strings). Reports are run on them and data graphed etc from db values.

I now need to have XML transmissions be received and the inserted directly into the MYSQL, with hopefully the same JSON layout. Then it will just work as if it was JSON and no other changes will be necessary anywhere else.

What would I need to do to achieve this? Broken down into steps for a novice would be much appreciated! So I can understand clearly what needs to be done and then attempt it.
Thankyou

Comment: Step 1) Figure out the differences between your xml and the expected json output. Step 2) Figure out what you need to do to get the expected json output. Step 3) Just do it.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**

Comment: Thanks for the help, part of my "figuring out" process was to ask. I will try and find an equivalent of SO that is more suited to those starting out/less experienced

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use this - https://github.com/tamlyn/xml2json
Of course such conversion is very specific to your use case, so you will have to scratch your head a little and tune that script to suit you.